# Angular formvalidation directive in chained module

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to implement an angular form validation "plugin". But I got stuck trying to use the directive in a child module.

I'm using the HighlightDirective example as a test.

```
@Directive({ selector: '[highlight]' })
/** Highlight the attached element in gold */
export class HighlightDirective {
  constructor(el: ElementRef) {
    el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = 'gold';
    console.log('* AppRoot highlight called for ${el.nativeElement.tagName}');
  }
}
```

I've created a module with sole purpose to validate forms

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { TestFormValidation } from './test.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    //define routes here
    { path: 'testformvalidation', component: TestFormValidation }
];

 @NgModule({
    imports: [],
    declarations: [TestFormValidation],
    bootstrap: [TestFormValidation]
})
export class FormValidation { }
```

I've imported both the directive and the form validation module in my main module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/
import { HighlightDirective } from './bugtracker/bugtracker.directive';
import { FormValidation } from './formvalidation/formvalidation.module';

import { Page1 } from './page1/page1.component';
import { Page2 } from './page2/page2.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
   { path: '', component: Page1 },
   { path: 'home', component: Page1 },
   { path: 'page2', component: Page2 },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes), FormValidation],
  declarations: [HighlightDirective, Page1, Page2],
  bootstrap: [],
  exports: [HighlightDirective]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

This works when I add the highlight attribute to page1 and page2.
eg:

```
<h3 highlight>Dashboard</h3>
```

But when I use this attribute in the component included via the form validation module, it is ignored.

my test component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    templateUrl: './app/formvalidation/test.component.html'
})
export class TestFormValidation{}
```

and finaly the template:

```
<h3 highlight>Form validation test page</h3>
```

Is it possible for the directive to be available to the child module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. There is no inheritance in angular modules. You have to define a Shared module, which you import in every module as needed. You can group shared functionality in a single module. In my example it is the FormValidation module. So change the main module to export the shared FormValidation module, and import the same in all modules whom require FormValidation:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/
import { HighlightDirective } from './bugtracker/bugtracker.directive';
import { FormValidation } from './formvalidation/formvalidation.module';

import { Page1 } from './page1/page1.component';
import { Page2 } from './page2/page2.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
   { path: '', component: Page1 },
   { path: 'home', component: Page1 },
   { path: 'page2', component: Page2 },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes), FormValidation],
  declarations: [HighlightDirective, Page1, Page2],
  bootstrap: [],
  exports: [FormValidation]
})
export class AppModule {}
```